# SonarQube on TeamCity vs SonarQube on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, teamcity, sonarqube

We are looking to switch from Jenkins to TeamCity and I am worried about SonarQube integration with TeamCity. I wasn't able to readily find this information from Sonar/TeamCity website, so just want to ask you guys.

Based on whatever I read, SonarQube plugin seems to work very well with Jenkins. Does it work at the same level with TeamCity as well? Are there any features that we can't use or is the user-experience any bad compared to Jenkins?

Answer (score 7):

There's not a plugin for TeamCity in the same way there is for Jenkins. But you can add a build step in TeamCity to run the analysis via command line pretty easily. I use the sonar-runner utility (we have C# projects, but should work fine with java/maven, etc).

If you want the per-build new issues report, you can utilize the Issues Report plugin to add a tab to the TeamCity build results, as I described here: https://www.wrightfully.com/adding-sonarqube-results-to-the-teamcity-build-page/

**Update:** TeamCity now has a native SonarQube runner option, which you can read about here: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/SonarQube+Integration

Comment: teamcity sonarqube runner doesn't work with maven projects, you still have to trigger the maven sonar:sonar goal.  So there still doesn't seem to be any way to show the issues in teamcity and push results to the sonar server.